# How do I find a previous element in a list?

Tags: python

```
n = 2
list1 = [1,4,6,2,8,9,90]
```

How would I go about finding the number prior to the number `n` stored above in `list1` and store it in the variable `list1_result`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate on what you tried so far to solve your problem? The Stack Overflow community wants to help you solve specific programming problems with _your_ code, but not write the code for you. So please, explain what you tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
List1 = [1,4,6,2,8,9,90]
n = 2
ind = List1.index(n)
list1_result = List1[ind-1] # is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the number in the list and then use that to find the previous element:

```
lst = [1,4,6,2,8,9,90]
the_index = lst.index(n)
lst2 = lst[the_index-1]
```

Now, you have the new list stored in lst2

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to find the index of `n` in the list then subtract 1 to get the position of the element before it.

```
n = 2
List1 = [1,4,6,2,8,9,90]
prev_elem = List1[List1.index(n) - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which will scan through your list and return the desired number if found a match with `n`
Try this:

```
def find_previous(List1, n):
    for i in range(len(List1)):
        if List1[i] == n and i > 0:
            return List1[i-1]
    return None
```